# Since when has the angular transformer required the dartSdk path be specified in pubspec.yaml?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I'm writing a new Angular.dart 1.0 app, and upon building, pub is giving me the following error:

```
Loading angular transformers... 
Error on line 15, column 3 of pubspec.yaml: Error loading transformer: Invalid arguments(s): sdkDirectory must be provided.
```

I had an Angular.dart app written against 0.14 that didn't require this.  I also went to look at the Angular.dart tutorial and there was no mention of this setting.  Having to actually specify it makes CI tricky.  Since when was this required, and is there a way to avoid specifying it in `pubspec.yaml` (environment variable, for example?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update

Should be fixed in `code_transformers` 0.2.3+2 (see http://dartbug.com/21225)

#### Old

See https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/issues/1270#issuecomment-64967674

If you create a symlink

```
ln -s /usr/lib/dart /usr/lib/dart/bin/dart-sdk
```

then you don't need the `sdkDirectory` in the transformer setting in the `pubspec.yaml` file.

This is very annoying. I also think that an environment variable would be the best solution, but seems this is not supported.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work for brew installations of dart on OS X

Comment: Is the link invalid or do you still get the error message? In which folder is the Dart SDK directory when Dart is installed using brew?

Answer (score 0):

It's still a problem with my environnement (macos + brew + code_transformers 0.2.3+2). Fixed with

`ln -s /usr/local/opt/dart/libexec /usr/local/opt/dart/libexec/bin/dart-sdk`

Edit: OR by using code_transformers 0.2.5 (see https://github.com/Netflix/security_monkey/issues/100)

I actually had to force it in pubspec.yaml :

```
dependency_overrides:
  code_transformers: 0.2.5
```